# I bricked my usb after a dd command, how can i recover it?

Tags: linux, usb, laptop

When I used a `dd` command on my usb to make it bootable, the `dd` command said there wasn't any space left. So I tried again, but it said "/dev/sda/: no medium found". However, if I connect my usb, the `lsblk` command does show a `/dev/sda`, and if I disconnect it, the `sda` in `lsblk` disappears. The kernel also recognises my usb, as `dmesg` shows me.

```
[36132.769314] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[36132.896845] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1e3d, idProduct=198a, bcdDevice= 1.00
[36132.896852] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[36132.898555] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[36132.898932] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[36133.927920] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ChipsBnk Flash Disk       5.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[36133.928507] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Media removed, stopped polling
[36133.929007] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

However, `fdisk` doesn't see my flash drive.
I believe I somehow bricked my usb drive, using that `dd` command, and I was wondering if there was any way I could recover it. It is also worth saying that I'm using Artix linux with `runit` as the init system.
I also tried to format the drive with mkfs, but it also returned "no medium found".

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to format the USB drive using regular format commands.

If that does not work, replace the USB drive.

It probably had a hardware issue before you started testing it.